# "Dann gehe ich halt" idiom meaning?

Tags: idiom

I noticed a german headline today that seemed like it might contain a somewhat common idiom (although maybe I'm wrong) of which I haven't been able to find a definition or explanation online:

["Wenn ich zurück nach Polen muss, dann gehe ich halt"](http://www.spiegel.de/wirtschaft/brexit-verunsichert-polen-und-andere-osteuropaeer-in-grossbritannien-a-1100074.html)

So the potential idiom in question is:

> dann gehe ich halt

or

> gehe ich halt

…or some similar variation. I've found some other examples of this phrase online, but no explanation.

I gather from the context of the linked article above it probably means something like, "I'm out of here". But it seems a bit strange to me that the phrase contains `halt`, which seems to indicate the opposite of rapid movement.

So is this a commonly (or uncommonly) used idiom or phrase? What does it mean, and how is it used?

Comment: You got the wrong word *halt*, consult your dictionary again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically, "halt" expresses *unimpressedness*.

> Juhu, wir sind Weltmeister! = We are the champions!
>
> Dann sind wir halt Weltmeister. =  So we're the champions. Big deal.

Comment: "Dann gehe ich *eben*" would be equivalent.

Comment: I always think of it as “just”. In this case, “then I’ll just go”. What about “es ist halt so”? I would say “that’s just how it is”.

Answer (score 1):

"halt" in this context has a meaning of "I am not happy with it but I will do". Similar to "so what" in English.